# Event in Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

The task is a User who buys a product, money is deducted from the user, but the user can refuse within 20 minutes, or not receive the service at all.

The product has a status that will be either active, or completed, or canceled.

How can I make it so that after 20 minutes, in the absence of actions by the buyer, the status switches to the closed state and the money is returned to the user's account?

I am using Postgresql database

I don't understand how to solve this problem

Comment: [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) or [pg_timetable](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/products/pg_timetable/).

Comment: You could try writing a BackgroundService in ASP.Net Core which keeps track of time and you can inject it via dependency injection.  Please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio